# Is the set $O:= \{(x,y) \in X \times X: d(x,y) < r \}$ Borel measurable?

Tags: probability, general-topology, probability-theory, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ a metric space and $\mathcal{X}$ its Borel sigma-algebra, i.e. the sigma-algebra generated by the open sets of $X$. Is the set $O:= \{(x,y) \in X \times X: d(x,y) < r \}$ $\mathcal{X} \otimes \mathcal{X}$-measurable, where $\mathcal{X} \otimes \mathcal{X}$ is the product sigma-algebra? My thought to show that was that $O=\bigcup_x \{x\} \times B(x,r)$ where $B(x,r)$ is the open ball of center $x$ and radius $r$...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The title and the body ask two different questions.

Is $O$ Borel measurable, i.e. in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the open sets of $X \times X$ (in the product topology)?  Yes, indeed it is itself an open set.

Is $O$ measurable with respect to the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{X}$?  Not necessarily.  See [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/39882/product-of-borel-sigma-algebras) and references therein.

Comment: I forgot to mention $X$ is separable.

Comment: @user44670: Ah.  When $X$ is separable then these two $\sigma$-algebras are identical, so the answer to your question in that case is an unambiguous "yes".

Comment: thanks for your quick answer, and sorry for the imprecisions.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the function $(x,y) \longmapsto d(x,y)$ is continuous on $X \times X$. Continuous functions are Borel measurable.

Comment: god I'm stupid. Thanks.